# 404 error while running Spring MVC webapp

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

While I am running the spring mvc dynamic web-app.It does not give any exception

in console but 404 error in browser and in console these I got.

```
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-

INF/troubleshootApplicationContext.xml]  


    11-Apr-2016 08:47:59 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader 

initWebApplicationContext


    INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 360 ms


    11-Apr-2016 08:47:59 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log


    INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'HelloWeb'


    11-Apr-2016 08:47:59 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet 

initServletBean


    INFO: FrameworkServlet 'HelloWeb': initialization started


    11-Apr-2016 08:47:59 

    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext 

prepareRefresh


    INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'HelloWeb-servlet': 

startup 

    date [Mon Apr 11 08:47:59 BST 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext


    11-Apr-2016 08:47:59 

    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  

loadBeanDefinitions


    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-

INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]


   11-Apr-2016 08:47:59 

   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping 

registerHandler


   INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello] onto handler 'troubleController'


   11-Apr-2016 08:47:59 

   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping 

registerHandler


   INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello.*] onto handler 'troubleController'


   11-Apr-2016 08:47:59 


   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping 

registerHandler


   INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello/] onto handler 'troubleController'


   11-Apr-2016 08:47:59 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet 


initServletBean


   INFO: FrameworkServlet 'HelloWeb': initialization completed in 495 ms


   11-Apr-2016 08:47:59 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start


   INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080


   11-Apr-2016 08:47:59 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init


   INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009


   11-Apr-2016 08:47:59 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start


   INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/21  config=null


   11-Apr-2016 08:47:59 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start


   INFO: Server startup in 1490 ms


   11-Apr-2016 08:48:00 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet 

noHandlerFound


   WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TS_WEB_APP/] in 

DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'

Web.xml
====

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>

      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>

      <servlet-class>

         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet


      </servlet-class>

      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

      <init-param>

    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>

    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>

  </init-param>

   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>

      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>

      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

   </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>

        <listener-

class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>

    </listener>

    </web-app>
```

## dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />

      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you have mapped all the URL's containing /hello to the `troubleController` , so in order to check that response , you could try and hit localhost:8080/YourWebAppName/hello , and replace the YourWebAppName with your web application project name.

The error that you get , indicates that for the URL /TS_WEB_APP/ there has not been set up any `@RequestMapping` to any controller

Comment: Here is the controller that i used
@Controller
//@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class TroubleController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
    public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
       model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

       return "hello11";
    }
}

Comment: yeap , you can see that from the logs also , that the /hello is being mapped to the `troubleController` , the problem is that your trying to hit the url /TS_WEB_APP/ which you havent mapped it ....... so the real question is what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I just wanted print some messages when the URL:: http://localhost:8080/TS_WEB_APP/hello gets hit.It suppose to show some messages.But when i try to hit this URL it shows 404.

Comment: Did i do anything wrong in controller's request mapping??

Comment: TS_WEB_APP is  my web-app project name

Comment: <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
         </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

Comment: ok try change your URL pattern in the web.xml from `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern> ` to `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> ` , also which web container are you using ?

Comment: ok in your WEB-INF folder , do you have a jsp named : hello11.jsp ?? because i see that in your controller , this is the value you return

Comment: same warning WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TS_WEB_APP/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'.Nothing comes up except 404

Comment: Yes there is one jsp named as hello11.jsp inside web-inf

Comment: are you deploying it as root context ? because the error indicates `WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TS_WEB_APP/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'` , could you try hit  localhost:8080/hello , and post the error

Comment: I directly run this web-app from eclipse.After hitting that url that you shared i didn't get any warning or any message in eclipse but in browser it shows 404

Comment: ok then you are deploying the web app with a different name , if you hit localhost:8080 , the Tomcat's main page should appear . In there you could see which wep apps are deployed and under which context. Also could you update your post with the full dispatcher-servlet configuration xml

Comment: I am able to open tomcat home page when i run this localhost:8080 and for your reference i posted the dispatchcer servlet and web.xml in beolw.

Comment: your conf looks ok with a fast check , can you double click on Tomcat in the Eclipse 's Server View and check in the Deployment Tab , under which context you are deploying you web app. Also , right click on your project , Properties > Web Project Settings and post the Context Root Name displayed there

Comment: I checked in Projects>Properties > Web Project Settings the context is TS_WEB_APP but I am not able to find any deployment tab after double clicking tomcat server in eclipse.

Comment: ok then it should reply properly when you are hitting that URL.  When you double click on the server , it opens up the server.xml Descriptor , if you check down below there must be a side tab Named : Deployement ,in there must be your wep app , with the /URL that is being deployed

Comment: When i double click the server then it opens server configuration page...No  server.xml

Comment: Same in server.xml also...<Context docBase="TS_WEB_APP" path="/TS_WEB_APP" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TS_WEB_APP"/></Host>

Comment: ok can you clean and redeploy Tomcat , and then try again hitting  localhost:8080/TS_WEB_APP/hello and post the exception again in case it throws one , also try to read properly the comments................

Comment: When I hit the URL http://localhost:8080/TS_WEB_APP/hello it shows below statements in eclipse console.org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TS_WEB_APP/WEB-INF/hello11.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'

Comment: ok better now , this is a valid exception ,  first where have you placed the .jsp files ? are they under WEB-INF/views or which directory? and second post the full code of your controller , there might be a mis-configuration

Comment: I Just pasted the my JSP inside web-inf only.....And the controller is @Controller
public class TroubleController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
    public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
       model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

       return "hello11";
    }
}

Comment: ok then fix in your dispatcher-servlet.xml the line from `  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />` to `  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />` or in whatever directory you have placed the .jsp

Comment: also you havent posted your full controller , because in the logs you shared , you are mapping again the /hello with /hello/ and /hello/* , which means you have set up another `@RequestMapping` annotation

Comment: I pasted my controller in above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the controller that i used

@Controller

//@RequestMapping("/hello")

public class TroubleController {

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")

   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {

      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

      return "hello11";

   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

dispatcher servlet

==========

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc

http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd   

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.myriad.ihc.controller" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />

   <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />

</bean>
```

Web.xml

==========

xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

Spring MVC Application

index.jsp

```
  <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>

  <servlet-class>

     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

  </servlet-class>

  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

  <init-param>

<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>

<param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
```

```
  <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>

  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my controller class and also i changed my my jsp page location to /WEB-INF/

@Controller

public class TroubleController {

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")

   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {

      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

      return "hello11";

   }
```

}